# Trouble in join and alias table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve a question where each worker from a specific department sells a product and makes 1000 in profit. I want to find out the profit or loss of the company for each month. Assuming that the only profit comes from the sales and costs are the salaries off all workers.

```
Table dept_worker
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
| worker_id | dept_n  | from_date  | to_date    |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
|  10002    |  25     | 1996-08-03 | 9999-01-01 |
|  10016    |  25     | 1998-02-11 | 9999-01-01 |
|  10034    |  25     | 1995-04-12 | 1999-10-31 |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+

Table salaries
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| worker_id| salary | from_date  | to_date    |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
|  10001   |  617   | 1986-04-26 | 1987-06-26 |
|  10002   |  600   | 1996-08-03 | 9999-01-01 |
|  10016   |  602   | 1998-02-11 | 9999-01-01 |
|  10034   |  674   | 1995-04-12 | 1999-10-31 |
|  10100   |  900   | 2000-07-25 | 2002-06-25 |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
```

I tried two different approaches. I tried using WHERE dept_n = '25' but the result wasn't the expected because I was filtering everything.

```
    SELECT MONTH(from_date) AS 'Months', COUNT(worker_id)*1000 AS 'Profit', 
    SUM (salary) AS 'Costs', (COUNT(worker_id)*1000-SUM(salary)) AS 'Diff'
    FROM dept_worker JOIN salaries using(from_date,worker_id)
    GROUP BY Month
    ORDER BY Diff DESC;
```

The second one (this query doesn't give me any result):

```
    SELECT MONTH(from_date) AS 'Months', 
    (SELECT COUNT(worker_id)*1000 FROM dept_worker WHERE dept_n = '25') AS 'Profits', SUM(salary) 
    FROM dept_worker JOIN salaries using(from_date)
    GROUP BY Months;
```

Expected result:

```
+----------+--------+------------+-------------------+
| Months   | Profits| Costs      | Profits - Costs   |
+----------+--------+------------+-------------------+
|  1       | 4456   |14478       |-10022             |
|  2       | 4105   |14824       |-10719             |
|  3       | 4379   |16130       |-11751             |
|  4       | 4329   |15562       |-11233             |
| (...)    | (...)  |(...)       |(...)              |         
+----------+--------+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I think you need a window function as below - is this helpful?

Comment: Where is the query where you had `WHERE dept_n = '25'` that was "filtering everything"? Your shown joins make little sense; the latter ignore which worker completely, and the former would only count a worker's initial salary. It looks like you need a "months" table to start from.

Comment: @Uueerdo I had the WHERE clause between FROM/GROUP BY.

Comment: @DanielMarcus Thanks for the help. I tried to use the window function but for some reason it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post your expected result.

Comment: @Uueerdo Result: A table like this `| Months| Profits | Costs  | Profits - Costs    |`

Comment: No, I mean edit your question to include actual expected values from the sample data you've already provided.

Comment: @DanielMarcus , nvm. 
I used the query `SELECT MONTH(from_date) AS 'Months', SUM(salary) FROM salaries GROUP BY Months;` to compare the SUM(salary) for each month with the query you provided and the results aren't the same.

Comment: @Uueerdo done...

Comment: "actual expected values"

Comment: How did you arrive at values such as 4456?

Answer (score 0):

Try Starting with this:

```
   SELECT MONTH(from_date) AS 'Months', COUNT(worker_id) over(partition by dept_n order by dept_n) * 1000 AS 'Profit', 
    SUM (salary) over(partition by dept_n order by dept_n) AS 'Costs' 
    FROM dept_worker JOIN salaries using(from_date,worker_id)
    GROUP BY  MONTH(from_date)
```

Comment: MySQL only added support for that kind of partitioning in 8.0. The first release that is not a "Development Milestone" or "Release Candidate", only came out less than a week ago (according to release notes [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/))

Comment: The OP says `MySQL`.  It's most likely there's no window function.  So don't post solution that doesn't work.